# Symmetric power lift of modular forms

Tags: rt.representation-theory, algebraic-number-theory, modular-forms, automorphic-forms, galois-representations

Let $f_1$ and $f_2$ be two cuspforms of weights $k_1$ and $k_2$ and nebentypus $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$ respectively such that $f_1 \neq f_2 \otimes \chi$ for some Dirichlet character $\chi$ of order $n$.

Is it possible that ${\rm sym}^n(f_1)$ is same as ${\rm sym}^n(f_2)$?

In other words, I am looking for a necessary and sufficient condition for two cuspforms to produce the same symmetric $n$-th representation for some fixed $n$.

Any help regarding this would be really appreciated.

Comment: Are you assuming these are newforms?

Comment: @Kimball Yes. Let's assume they are newform.

Comment: Do you know about the works of Ramakrishnan and Rajan?

Comment: Just for clarification: you're thinking about $GL_2$, rather than fancier things?

Comment: @paulgarrett Yes.

Answer (score 2):

This can happen.  For example, the dihedral group $D$ of order $10$ has two irreducible (Galois conjugate) representations $U$ and $V$ of dimension $2$ which are not twists of each other. But $\mathrm{Sym}^3(U) = \mathrm{Sym}^3(V)$. Now just take $f$ to be associated to an Artin representation with image $D$ and let $g$ be the Galois conjugate and you have an example. Similar things happen with other representations with small image.

If the Zariski closure of the image of (either of the) Galois representations associated to $f_1$ or $f_2$ contains $\mathrm{GL}_2$ however then such an equality forces them to be twists. The idea in this case is that $\mathrm{Sym}^2(U) \mathrm{det}(U)^{-1}$ will be the unique $3$-dimensional constituent of $\mathrm{Sym}^n(U) \otimes \mathrm{Sym}^n(U)^{\vee}$. This reduces the problem to showing that an equality of irreducible representations $\mathrm{Sym}^2(U) \mathrm{det}(U)^{-1} = \mathrm{Sym}^2(V) \mathrm{det}(V)^{-1}$ implies that $U$ and $V$ are twists, which I assume since it is the first special case of your question you already know.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried to understand it but could not figure it out. Can you provide some references?

Comment: If we consider complex Galois representation, then the image in $\mathrm{PGL}_2(\mathbb{C})$ is always small and we know what can be the image. So by big image, I think you are talking about $\ell$-adic Galois representation.

Comment: Ah sorry, I should have asked the question more precisely. Yes I know the group $D_{10}$, its complex representations and all the things you mentioned as it is nothing but representation theory of finite groups. I would like to read in detail what you mentioned in the second paragraph of your answer as I have very little knowledge about it. In particular, I am interested to know when the image of a Galois representation attached to a modular form is very big. Please suggest some references regarding this.

Comment: https://www.claymath.org/library/proceedings/cmip013c.pdf Here, in page no 483, the author showed that two cusp forms can give same symmetric cube without being a twist of each other. So I'm not able to understand what you wrote in the second paragraph of your answer.

Comment: Can we say that if $f$ is a non-CM form, then the Zariski closure of the Galois representation contains ${\mathrm{GL}}_2$?